# C# convert reflection.propertyinfo to Generic.List<>

Tags: c#, reflection, generic-list, propertyinfo

How do I go about converting a reflection.propertyinfo[] to a generic.list<>?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var list = yourArray.ToList();
```

Comment: @Ed - still, at least you have the 3.0 compiler. Btw, have you tried LinqBridge?

Comment: Nope, VS 2005 for us unfortunately (I meant to say C# 2.0).  I haven't tried LinqBridge, but I'll take a look.  We are about to rewrite the front end UI to the machine that I develop at work, so I'm trying to talk the execs into letting us upgrade.  Wish me luck :)

Comment: @Ed sorry, I was basing that on your use of `var`

Comment: Not a bad assumption.  I have picked up plenty of C# 3.0+ stuff by way of forums and reading blogs, but I don't get to use them often.  Most of the code I write at home is in C or C++.  I like writing hardware interfaces and I'm afraid I've become a bit of a dinosaur at age 27 :D.  Anyway, +1 since your suggestion is what I would have recommended had I known the method existed.

Answer (score 6):

One of the `List<T>` constructors accepts an `IEnumerable<T>` as its argument (i.e., your PropertyInfo array):

```
var list = new List<PropertyInfo>( propInfoArray );
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using .ToList()

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx

Answer (score 0):

All of the above are correct. But it should also be mentioned that, like `List<T>` all .net arrays implement `IList<T>`.

```
  var IList<PropertyInfo> ilist = reflection.propertyinfo;
```

Since I know that, almost all my functions accept `IList<T>` when I need a list-like collection, which I can use with traditional arrays and lists.

Answer (score -1):

Use the extension method `ToList()` available in the `System.Linq` namespace:

```
var myProperties = propertyInfoArray.ToList();
```

Comment: Reflection property does not has .ToList method defined.

Comment: As I said, this is an extension method. This solution also happens to be the accepted answer as suggested by Nylo Andy above. This should not be downvoted. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396